How can i fix the event index issue in my angular drag-and-drop?
This is a rought draft of a trello clone.  A UI that lets you drag around lists and cards, and move cards between lists.  The drag events are having issues because it seems like the indexes for the dragged cards are being generated at the board level instead of the list level.  If you drag card 5 to drop just below card 1, it will jump to the bottom of the list.  If you drag card 1 to just below card 6, the wrong card drops.  Live code / demo here:  https://stackblitz.com/github/HokieBytes/board-app?file=src%2Fapp%2Fboard%2Fboard.component.html
